# CONCAT n VALUES

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple fields name as this

```
custom_1_field
custom_2_field
custom_3_field
.
.
custom_N_field
```

I never know how much custom_N_fields. I need to concat all of them.

I can concate with this code if i kwow how much fields i have

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',custom_1_field,CONCAT('<hr>',custom_2_field)) AS new_field
```

But if i don't know how much N `custom_N_fields` I have, what can i do?

There are something like `CONCAT custom_N_fields` where `'N'` it's any number?

EDIT: i use php+sql

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using to generate your mysql statement?

Comment: Sorry. I edit post. I use PHP

Comment: You can concat() all fields, but only return first N of concat(). Will this work for you?

Comment: So how do you know how many fields you have? (How do you know N?)

Comment: <criticism> It is poor design to have "arrays" as columns in a table.</criticism>

Comment: PeterBowers I don't Know N.
cyadvert N it's a uknown number. I need to concat all fields that have custom_anynumber_fields
RickJames I don't understand what you say
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like the SQL answer I suggested above, you could very easily (much 
more easily!) solve the problem within PHP (or whatever programming platform you are using).  Simply do your query and grab the list of fields from the resulting query on the first fetch and then construct your string from those fields.  Something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ...';
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$field_list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if (!$field_list) {
        $field_list = preg_grep('/^custom_\d+_field$/', array_keys($row));
    }
    // work with $row until you need the concatenated field...
    // then use this snippet to construct the concatenated field
    $newstr = $sep = '';
    foreach ($field_list as $f) {
        $newstr = $sep.$row[$f];
        $sep = ' '; // this will be put in front of all the rest of the fields
    }
    // now echo your $newstr or whatever you want to do with it
}
```

I would be interested in feedback from others on the construction of the string using $sep as I have done it - it's a construction I use often and it feels inelegant and inefficient and I'd be interested in a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty weird, but this should do it - look up the list of fields first and then each one that matches your pattern gets put in the `CONCAT(...)` column:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT CONCAT_WS(" "';
$q = mysqli_query($conn, 'DESCRIBE tablename');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    if (preg_match("/custom_\d+_field/", $row['Field']))
        $sql .= ",".$row['Field'];
$sql .= ') AS new_field';
# $sql .= "FROM someTable WHERE x = y";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    # do stuff with $row['new_field']
}
?>
```

Looks like you want to do something with `<hr>` tags in there as well - it should be relatively trivial to extend the example to do that.

Comment: I don't know how many N fields have database. It can be 0 or 1000 fields. I need to concat all of them without know how many custom_NUMBER_fields i have

Comment: Is that closer to what you were looking for? I haven't tried it myself, but I think it should be relatively close...

Comment: I think that it can works fine. I try it and i tell you. Thanks

Comment: One question. Is there any wildcatd inside CONCAT?

Comment: Do you mean to say `CONCAT(custom_*_field)` kind of thing? I've never heard of such a beast if it exists...

Comment: Is it not working for you? Or are you just looking to see if there's a simpler way?

Comment: I looking a simple way because on this select there are many fields with other connectors like LEFT JOIN, WHERES, HAVING and i'm not an mySQL expert to include this funcition on it ;) Look at this http://pastebin.com/03rxZVVK You can look contactos_0_nombre and others that can be concat with N fields ;)

Comment: Sorry - I've answered the question as stated. You can see where I initialize the start of the `SELECT` statement and where I append on the rest above - you should be able to just copy/paste your existing query.